# Programmatically load Entity in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, schema

I am trying to load in Entity classes and use within a loop in order to load content in dynamically from files into relating tables.

Is there any way i can load in all Entity files from the following

```
use AppBundle\Entity\aaPostcode;
use AppBundle\Entity\abPostcode;
use AppBundle\Entity\acPostcode;
use AppBundle\Entity\adPostcode;
```

in such a way like this?

```
use AppBundle\Entity\*
```

Not sure if this is possible in Symfony.

My next issue is using the the prefixedEntity within a loop like so -

```
new $entityPrefix
```

When i am setting $entityPrefix to the following format

```
$entityPrefix = str_replace([".csv"], "", $entityFilename) . "Postcode" . '()';
```

which returns the string of

```
"abPostcode()"
```

can anyone advise as to why calling

```
new $entityPrefix;
```

is not working

Thanks in advance for any help!

trying to call

```
new $entityPrefix();
```

returns

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]           
Attempted to load class "abPostcode" from the global namespace.      
Did you forget a "use" statement for "AppBundle\Entity\abPostcode"?
```

even when i current am hrd coding the use stament to call

```
use AppBundle\Entity\abPostcode;
```

Comment: you can try `$entityPrefix = 'abPostcode';` and then `new $entityPrefix();`

Comment: Thanks @kunicmarko20 have tried this and still returns the following error

Comment: Error in question

Comment: You can't do this `use AppBundle\Entity\*`. I'd suggest just loading the appropriate class `$entityPrefix = "AppBundle\Entity\" . str_replace([".csv"], "", $entityFilename) . "Postcode";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by pulling out the functionality into a helper and running a switch statement based on the input - in this case a {prefix}

Comment: How? I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instanciate dynamically your class without ginving the full namespace. Try that :

```
$namespace = "AppBundle\Entity\\";
$entityName = "YourEntity";
$namespace .= $entityName;
$class = new $namespace();
```

This is working for me...

Answer (score 0):

I kinda ran into this issue migrating data from one database type to another. IE: Oracle to MySQL. With hundreds of tables the use section would get big.

This is on Symfony 5.2.x BTW.

When I run a query using a standard repository or a repository linked to the table I can call the entity with its full namespace.

```
$oracle = $em2->getRepository(\App\Entity\Oracle\Appoints::class)->Appoints();
```

So I did not have to load "use App\Entity\Oracle\Appoints

Then I can create a new object in the same way:

```
$mysqlObject = new \App\Entity\OracleAppPoints();
```